# Abrir nueva tab con AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

Estoy tratando de visualizar un PDF que me devuelve una API.

El código con el cuál funcionaba hasta ahora es este:

```
$http.get(urlApi,{responseType:'arraybuffer'})
      .success(function(data) {

        var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        window.open(fileURL);

      });
```

Hasta ahora funcionaba correctamente, pero desde hace un par de días al abrirse la nueva pestaña, se cierra instantáneamente.

He estado realizando pruebas y con el código:

```
window.open(fileURL, "_self");
```

Funciona correctamente, el problema es que, evidentemente, se abre en la misma pestaña, y no es lo que busco, necesito que se habrá en una nueva.

¿Se os ocurre alguna idea de como poder abrir el PDF en una nueva pestaña sin que se cierre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución es: **Desinstalar Adblock**

Comment: Me alegro de que hayas resuelto el problema ;)

Answer (score 1):

Para abrir una nueva pestaña usa:

```
window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
```

Answer (score 1):

Según esta [documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) usando `_blank` te serviría.

Comment: Fue lo primero que probé y no funciona tampoco, se cierra automáticamente.

Comment: No tendrás algún bloqueador de ventanas emergentes o algo así?